# Creating multiple Rx Subjects in python with a for

Tags: python, python-3.x, reactive-programming

I'm trying to create a `Subject` and 2 `Observables` for each `cam` in `cams`. I'm preventing the objects from being deleted by holding them inside a `Cam` class and storing a `Cam` class instance for each `cam`, inside `cam_holder`. The problem here is: I end up with 3 rx repeaters that all work for the last `cam` in `cams`, not for each one. Can somebody find what's wrong?

```
cam_holder = {}

class Cam():
    cam = None
    watchdog = None
    buffer_signal = None
    stream = None
    repeater = None

for cam in cams:
    unique_id = str(cam.ip) + ':' + str(cam.onvif)
    cam_holder[unique_id] = Cam()
    c = cam_holder[unique_id]
    c.cam = cam
    c.cam.log('starting watchdog')

    c.watchdog = rx.subject.Subject()

    c.buffer_signal = rx.create(lambda observable, _: c.watchdog.subscribe(observable)).pipe(
        ops.filter(lambda x: x==Camera.COMPLETE_BUFFER)
    )

    c.stream = rx.create(lambda observable, _: c.watchdog.subscribe(observable)).pipe(
        ops.buffer_when(lambda: c.buffer_signal)
    )

    c.stream.subscribe(
        on_next = lambda i: process_camera_condition(c.cam,i),
        on_error = lambda e: c.cam.log(e),
        on_completed = lambda: None,
    )

    c.buffer_signal.subscribe(
        on_next = lambda i: None,
        on_error = lambda e: c.cam.log(e),
        on_completed = lambda: None,
    )

    c.repeater = rx.interval(QUERY_INTERVAL).pipe(
        ops.do_action(lambda x: c.cam.watchdog(c.watchdog,None))
    )

    c.repeater.subscribe(
        on_next = lambda i: None,
        on_error = lambda e: c.cam.log(e),
        on_completed = lambda: None,
    )
```